# Car battery drainage

Tags: car, battery-drain

I own a 2007 Ford Focus SE 2.0
My question is would you happen to know the reason why my battery (which is brand new) is always dead. I constantly have to disconnect the battery in order to be able to start my car again. It's very frustrating can you please help out in any way?
Thank you Lorraine

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have parasitic drain.  Something is not turning off in your car so even though you have turned the car off some devices are still drawing on your battery.  With a large enough load it drains your battery.  If you have a multi-meter you can test each fuse to isolate which fuse is still drawing power and see what devices run on that fuse.  Turn your car off and let the car sit for 30 minutes and then test the fuses.  Anything over 50 milli-amp will likely drain your battery as the car sits over night.

Comment: If you don’t have a meter use a small 12Vdc bulb, in series with ground when off and close doors and pull fuses till off then lookup function. Don’t leave it dead more than a few days

Comment: I actually disagree about 50 milli-amps being a problem. If you have 45 Ah battery, 50 milli-amps mean the battery is empty in 37 and half days. That sounds very much like the current draw of a smart key system.